# New to Stock Trading

Tags: united-states, investing

I'm very new to trading stocks. I have an online account with Ameritrade. I understand the difference between the Bid/Ask quotes. Are there any online tutorials out the so I can educate myself more in the In' & Out's of trading? Any help or guidance will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately product or service recommendations are off-topic for this site because they tend to be opinion-based and change over time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good ones, no there are not.  Go to a bookstore and pick up a copy of "The Intelligent Investor."  It was last published in 1972 and is still in print and will teach you everything you need to know.  If you have accounting skills, pick up a copy of "Security Analysis" by Benjamin Graham.  The 1943 version was just released again with a 2008 copyright and there is a 1987 version primarily edited by Cottle (I think).  The 1943 book is better if you are comfortable with accounting and the 1987 version is better if you are not comfortable and feel you need more direction.

I know recent would seem better, but the fact that there was a heavy demand in 2008 to reprint a 1943 book tells you how good it is.  I think it is in its 13th printing since 2008.  The same is true for the 72 and 87 book.  Please don't use internet tutorials.  If you do want to use Internet tutorials, then please just write me a check now for all your money.  It will save me effort from having to take it from you penny by penny because you followed bad advice and lost money.  Someone has to capture other people's mistakes.  Please go out and make money instead.

Prudence is the mother of all virtues.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll pick these up and start expanding my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Investopedia got some good tutorials on stocks and a good simulator to play around without loosing hard earned money.

http://www.investopedia.com/university/stocks/

http://www.investopedia.com/simulator/